# Can't Instantiate the type

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Have this code in my mainactivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnSendSMS;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
}
```

ADT says that :         btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot intantiate a View.OnClickListener with an empty constructor. You need to instantiate an anonymous class for that.

Example:

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO your code
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add anonymous click listener do it that way

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick (View v) {
          // your code
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
```

1)That's the implementation you need!
2)Try to rebuild your project anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> ADT says that : btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new
>   View.OnClickListener()); cannot be instantiated.

I believe  `View.OnClickListener()` is either an *abstract class or an interface*. In java You cannot **instantiate an interface or an Abstract class**, thus you get an error. I believe you need an *anonymous inner class* in place of instantiation.

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new ViewOnClickListener() {
       //your implemneting method from ViewOnClickListener     
});
```